# Calculate temperature decrease of an evaporating droplet

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

I have a small droplet of Cyclohexane which evaporates at room temperature and ambient pressure. I measured the volume at two different times ($\Delta V=1.5\times10^{-10}$ m$^3$).

I would like to calculate $\Delta T$ assuming all $\Delta H_{\text{evap}}$ comes from the thermal capacity of cyclohexane ($\Delta H_{\text{vaporization}} = 32$ kJ/mol).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't some heat flow from the surrounding air to the drop?

Comment: Probably yes, but the surrounding of the droplet is a small chamber that it is closed. So in principle, there is not much of air flowing in the surroundings.

Comment: How much mass of air is in the chamber compared to the mass of the drop?

Comment: I would say it's neglectable. The chamber must be 70 liters and the droplet is 2.5 microliters.

Comment: So all the heat comes from the surrounding air, and there is virtually no change in the temperature of the drop.

Comment: Exactly. Nothing, appart from the surrounding air, is heating the droplet.

Comment: So the droplet temperature change is insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that the droplet to start with has n molecules. As each molecule leaves the droplet it extracts an energy equal to enthalpy of vaporization divided by the Avogadro number. This is shared by n-1 molecules left in the droplet.  If C is the heat capacity per mole. There will be a corresponding decrease in temperature which can be calculated. But since the droplet is continuously shrinking, you have accommodate for that with n changing from initial volume to final volume.